# Mid as target of an assignment

Tags: c#, vb.net

I try just an old VB application in c# to convert, while I've encountered this line of code:

```
Mid(strData, intPosition + 1, intLenght) = strValue
```

How can it be translated into c#?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a _code converter_. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: Need more surrounding code. Is this a `conditional`?

Comment: Hope this help: 
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(strData) Then
 
 Mid(strData, intPosition + 1, intLenght) = strValue
 
 intPosition += intLenght
 
End If

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to combine [`Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.remove.aspx) and [`Insert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.string.insert.aspx), something like:

```
strData.Remove(intPosition, intLenght).Insert(intPosition, strValue);
```

The above assumes that the length of `strValue` was equal to `intLenght`. If `strValue` might be longer, then to replicate the [`Mid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz5s6003%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) statement, we would need to do:

```
strData.Remove(intPosition, intLenght)
       .Insert(intPosition, strValue.Substring(0, intLenght));
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That looks very good and is probably exactly what I've been looking :-)

Comment: @peter70 I was fascinated by this, so I decompiled a VB.NET app that contained your code and have uploaded the C# version to pastebin. Its quite interesting! See it here: http://pastebin.com/Lf6XwjMc